# Creating ASP.NET Button dynamically using ajax call

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want to create a asp.net button control / link button control when user makes an ajax call to my server page (another asp.net page) and I wnt to do something on the button click event of this button. How to do this ? Do i need to use delegate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need a delegate for this, it will be created for you. In your AJAX callback you should do something like this:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Click += MyOnClickMethod;     // must use +=, not =
btn.Text = "click me";
myUpdatePanel.Controls.Add(btn);  // the AJAX UpdatePanel that you want to add it to
myUpdatePanel.Update();           // refresh the panel
```

The method MyOnClickMethod must have the same signature as a normal Click handler. Something like this will do:

```
protected void MyOnClickMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   // do something
}
```

that's about it. There are many intricacies involved with dynamic controls, but the basis is as laid out above.