# Error: System.Web.HttpException: Failed to load viewstate. The control tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, updatepanel

I am getting an error in asp.net 4.5 when i dynamically create two buttons in (asp:GridView)_DATABOUND event.

Error:System.Web.HttpException: Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

The grid name is gvwRoutes and its gvwRoutes.RowEditing method execute the whole page crash. but this error occurs when any event fired after gvwRoutes.RowEditing event is fired

code for button:

```
            Dim btn1 As New Button()
            btn1.ID = "btn1"
            btn1.Width = "50"
            btn1.Text = "Edit"
            btn1.CssClass = "AdminPageBtn"
            btn1.CommandName = "Edit"
            btn1.CommandArgument = "Edit"
            btn1.Enabled = True


    e.Row.Cells(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1).Controls.Add(btn1)
```

And I'm using AJAX 4.0 too, with script manager and update panel.

```
Protected Sub gvwRoutes_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles gvwRoutes.RowEditing

    End Sub
```

What should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565539/creating-asp-net-button-dynamically-using-ajax-call

this may give you some idea

Comment: I have tried that, It's not the problem.. And I can't access UpdatePanel from codebehind